# SubmitForm then Patch results in "The data returned by the service was invalid"

Tags: azure-sql-database, powerapps

I'm building a PowerApps app on Azure SQL

### The requirement

I have a form which has "Save" and "Confirm" buttons.

Both buttons should save the form data. The Commit button should also set database column "Confirm" to 1

I've read at length about how I can programatically override the update value of a hidden control for this. But I'm not satisfied with the level of complexity (maintenance) required to get this working, i.e.

1. Populate a variable with the current db value
2. In the button code set the variable value
3. In the form field, set the update property to the variable

### What I'm Trying

So I'm trying a different approach: `SubmitForm` then `Patch`. Even though this requires an extra database call, I'd like to understand if this will work. This is the code for `OnSelect` in the commit button:

```
// Save the record
SubmitForm(frmEdit);

// Update confirmed to 1
Patch('[dbo].[Comments]',cRecord,{Confirmed:1});
```

### Some Complexities

Note that my record is a variable, `cRecord`. In short I want this app to be able to upsert based on URL parameters.

This is my `App.OnStart` which captures URL values, inserts a record if required. Regardless, the result of this event is that `cRecord` is set to the record to be edited.

```
// Cache employees and store lookups (as they are in a different db)
Concurrent(Collect(cEmployees, Filter('[dbo].[SalesPerson]', Status = "A")),Collect(cStores, '[dbo].[Store]'));

// Check for parameters in the URL. If found, set to Edit/Add mode
Set(bURLRecord,If((!IsBlank(Param("PersonId")) && !IsBlank(Param("Date"))),true,false));



// If URL Parameters were passed, create the record if it doesn't exist
If(bURLRecord,
    Set(pPersonId,Value(Param("PersonId")));
    Set(pDate,DateValue(Param("Date")));   
    // Try and find the record 
    Set(cRecord,LookUp('[dbo].[Comments]',SalesPersonId=pPersonId && TransactionDate = pDate));
    If(IsBlank(cRecord),
        // If the record doesn't exist, create it with Patch and capture the resulting record
        Set(cRecord,Patch('[dbo].[Comments]',Defaults('[dbo].[Comments]'),{SalesPersonId:pPersonId,TransactionDate:pDate}))
    );
    // Navigate to the data entry screen. This screen uses cRecord as its item
    Navigate(scrEdit);
)
```

`frmEdit.Item` is set to `cRecord`. As an aside I also have a gallery that sets this variable value when clicked so we can also navigate here from a gallery.

The navigating using new and existing URL parameters works. Navigating from the gallery works.

### The problem

When I press the Commit button against a record which has Confirmed=0 I get this popup error:

> The data returned by the service is invalid

When I run this code against a record which already has Confirmed=1 I don't get an error

If I run the PowerApps monitor it doesn't show any errors but it does show some counts being run after the update. I can paste it here if required.

I also tried wrapping the `Path` in a `Set` in case it's result was confusing the button event but it didn't make a difference.

### What I want

So can anyone offer me any of the following info:

1. How can I get more info about "The data returned by the service is invalid"?
2. How can I get this to run without erroring?
3. Is there a simpler way to do the initial upsert? I was hoping a function called `Patch` could upsert in one call but it seems it can't
4. With regards to the setting field beforehand approach, I'm happy to try this again but I had some issues implementing it - understanding which control where to edit.

Any assistance appreciated.

### Edit

As per recommendations in the answer, I moved the patch code into `OnSuccess`

```
If(Confirmed=1,Patch('[dbo].[CoachingComments]',cRecord,{Confirmed:1}));
```

But now I get the same error there. Worse I cleared out `OnSucces` and just put `SubmitForm(frmEdit);` into the `OnSelect` event and it is saving data but still saying

> The data returned by the service was invalid

Comment: Where is the `OnSelect` code for the `Commit` button?

Comment: Good point - I've edited to make it clearer

Answer (score 0):

First things first,
Refactoring has multiple steps,
I can t type all out at once...
The submitform and patch issue:

Never use the submitforn with extra conplexity
Submitform is only the trigger to send the form out,
The form handler will work with your data...
If you hsven t filled out the form correctly, u don t want to trigger your patch action...
So:
On your form, you have an OnSucces property,
Place your patch code there...
Change your cRecord in your patch statement:
YourForm.LastSubmit

Comment: I will try this and get back to you but this makes perfect sense! There is also a lot of gold in there about `YourForm.LastSubmit`

Comment: you make me curious too ;-)

Comment: I apologise that it's taken so long to get back to you. I just realised if I put the patch in the the OnSuccess event, it will call it regardless of whether I pushed the save button or the commit button. Is there any way to know or do I need to set a local variable and check that?

Comment: Believe it or not I now get the same error against the OnSuccess event.